# how to use objects and reference variables in event handling class

Tags: java, user-interface, oop, reference, event-handling

So I have two classes, one in which my GUI is created and the second to handle events.

I have a JCheckBox in my GUI, I want to change the text of the JButton's once the JCheckBox has been checked.

Here are the following classes, Gui:

```
           import javax.swing.*;
           import java.awt.*;

 public class Motion extends JFrame {

MotionEvent controller = new MotionEvent();

//row 0
JPanel row0 = new JPanel();

//row 1
JPanel row1 = new JPanel();
JButton up = new JButton("Up");

//row 2
JPanel row2 = new JPanel();
JButton left = new JButton("Left");
JButton right = new JButton("Right");
JCheckBox compassFormat = new JCheckBox("compassFormat", false);

//row 3 
JPanel row3 = new JPanel();
JButton down = new JButton("Down");

Motion(){
super("Motion Detector");
setSize(500,325);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
GridLayout layoutMaster = new GridLayout(5,1,10,10);
setLayout(layoutMaster);
add(row0);

FlowLayout layout1 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER);
row1.setLayout(layout1);
up.addActionListener(controller);
row1.add(up);
add(row1);

GridLayout layout2 = new GridLayout(1, 3, 10, 10);
row2.setLayout(layout2);
left.addActionListener(controller);
compassFormat.addItemListener(controller);
right.addActionListener(controller);
row2.add(left);
row2.add(compassFormat);
row2.add(right);
add(row2);

FlowLayout layout3 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER);
row3.setLayout(layout3);
row3.add(down);
add(row3);

setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args){
Motion passedInGui = new Motion();
}
}
```

Event Handler:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MotionEvent implements ActionListener, ItemListener{

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
Object objSource = event.getActionCommand();
if(objSource.equals("Up")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have moved up", "Navigator",           JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
else if(objSource.equals("Down")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have moved down", "Navigator", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
else if(objSource.equals("Left")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have moved left", "Navigator", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
else if(objSource.equals("Right")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have moved right", "Navigator", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
}

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
    Object objS = event.getStateChange();

    if(objS.equals(ItemEvent.SELECTED)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Need help on stackOverflow", "Tester", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

    }
 }
 }
```

The line where I create a messageDialog within the itemStateChanged method, I want to replace this with a line that'll allow me to change the text of the JButtons.

something along the lines of... Motion.down.setText("South");

How would I go about doing this? I know I'll need a reference variable of some sort. The reference variable must be defined within the methods, for if it is outside a stackoverflow error will occur.

Comment: Pass Motion as parameter to MotionEvent during creation of MotionEvent. MotionEvent will have one more constructor like this public MotionEvent(Motion motion){ this.motion = motion;} and you should have getter methods for attributes you have to change

Comment: @sunrise76 error, motion cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: You have to import the class Motion in MotionEvent. When you are creating MotionEvent in Motion, you have to pass "this" in constructor for MotionEvent

Comment: public class Motion{

 private String buttonLabel;

 public Motion(){
  MotionEvent evt = new MotionEvent(this);
 }
 public static void main(String args[]){
  Motion m = new Motion();
 }
 public void setButtonLabel(String str){
  this.buttonLabel = str;
 }
 public String getButtonLabel(){
  return buttonLabel;
 } 
} --  public class MotionEvent{

 private Motion motion;
 public MotionEvent(Motion motion){
  this.motion = motion;

 }
 public void someMethod(){
  motion.setButtonLabel("SomeTxt");
 }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public class Motion{

```
private String buttonLabel;

public Motion(){
    MotionEvent evt = new MotionEvent(this);
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    Motion m = new Motion();
}
public void setButtonLabel(String str){
    this.buttonLabel = str;
}
public String getButtonLabel(){
    return buttonLabel;
}
```

}

public class MotionEvent{

```
private Motion motion;
public MotionEvent(Motion motion){
    this.motion = motion;

}
public void someMethod(){
    motion.setButtonLabel("SomeTxt");
}
```

}

Comment: Declare both classes in same package